# Plotting Dates for my X-Axis for Chart.js

Tags: html, perl, chart.js

I am trying to make a chart that will display `DT`  for the X-Axis (Format: MM/DD/YYYY) and `CNT` for the Y-Axis. I have the chart displaying but for some reason it's not plotting the graph. Any help will be highly appreciated. Seems like a simple mistake that I can't figure out.
Full Code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST GET);
use CGI qw/:standard /;
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
# Connect to the database
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:ODBC:SMSDWDE2','username','password',{RaiseError =>1, AutoCommit=>1});
# Prepare and execute a SQL query
my $sql = "SELECT dt, Count(state) cnt
FROM (SELECT Trunc(hist_in_dttm) dt, state
FROM trk_id_act
WHERE grp_type = 720
AND hist_in_dttm >= Trunc(SYSDATE) - 30
AND state IN ('DOWN')
and (trk_id LIKE 'WSI01%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI02%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI03%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI04%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI05%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI06%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI07%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI08%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI09%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI10%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI13%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI15%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI16%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI17%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI19%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI20%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI21%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI22%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI23%' or trk_id LIKE 'WSI24%' or
trk_id LIKE 'WSI25%' or trk_id LIKE 'WS501%')
)
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt DESC";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
# Fetch data from the query results and store it in an array
my @data = ();
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
push @data, $row;
}
# Extract columns for the chart
my @dates = map { $->{'dt'} } @data;
my @counts = map { $->{'cnt'} } @data;
# Generate the HTML page with Chart.js
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>\n";
print "<head>\n";
print "<title>Daily Fail Events</title>\n";
print "<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js'></script>\n";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "<canvas id='myChart'></canvas>\n";
print "<script>\n";
print "var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');\n";
print "var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {\n";
print "type: 'line',\n";
print "data: {\n";
print "labels: [". join(',', map {"'$_'"} @dates) ."],\n";


print "datasets: [\n";
print "{\n";
print "label: 'Daily Count', \n";
print "data: [". join(',', @counts) ."], \n";


print "backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',\n";
print "borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',\n";
print "borderWidth: 1\n";
print "},\n";
print "]\n";
print "},\n";
print "options: {\n";
print "scales: {\n";
print "xAxes: [{\n";
print "ticks: {\n";
print "beginAtZero: true, max: 10000 \n";
print "}\n";
print "}]\n";
print "}\n";
print "}\n";
print "});\n";
print "</script>\n";
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";
```

SQL: Output is correct
[image]

WebPage:
[image]

Adding Web Dev View:
[image]

Comment: I can see that you are using the latest version of chart.js but the options for axes are from an older version; check [the migration guide enbtry on scales](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html#scales). That probably cancels out with the fact that the two options `ticks.beginAtZero` and `ticks.max` don't exist. I strongly recommend that you add to your post the final html+js code from browser's  "view page source" or "show page source", that is the page after perl has executed - this can be replicated by anyone and we can see exactly where the problem comes from.

Comment: I just added the inspect view to the post. I hope this helps.

Comment: I can only see that you haven't changed the configuration of the x scale as per my previous message (change `xAxes: [{` to `x: {` as stated in the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html#scales) + the delete the closing `]`). Otherwise, it is not very helpful, we can't debug images. Please consider posting the source code from the browser, is there a reason for not doing so? If you have privileged data for the chart, consider creating an example with fake/simplified data.